# The Stern-Gerlach Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Spin is an intrinsic property that always confused me in the time I considered theoretical physics.

But I have taken a slight turn, and decided to couple my love of analytic number theory with a hobbyist pursuit of becoming a competent lacky in an experimental physics laboratory.

So I want to know what the present day standards for reproducing these results are, in terms of the experimental apparatus schematics, if their conclusions are still considered valid.

The material I could find in English so far will be linked to this question.

[enter link description here](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2016/entries/physics-experiment/app5.html)

Comment: See https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1574321 and https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1974201 to start. Why do you think the results might not still be considered valid?

Comment: Well no I only selected this arbitrarily as an objective for the sake of becoming proficient with apparatus design. I will leave those considerations for after and the conclusive reporting of the successful replication of the accepted standard of methodology

Comment: Well, the two papers listed show you how to set up the experiment in an undergraduate university lab, so have at it!

Comment: ok I suppose that ought to have been submitted as the shortest answer on record, it's selfish really I broadcast it as a question to prevent my own navigation selecting an inferior manual\

Comment: But thankyou none the less

Comment: From what I have read so far it I can see how electron spin could potentially explain their result, and that other models clearly fail to explain it, but it really does depend on a hands on knowledge of apparatus at least for me personally I need that first

Comment: while a noble goal, by the time you get to the Higgs boson you are going to be in deep trouble if you have to have hands-on experience with all the experimental equipment...

Comment: oh well then the associated social media campaigns photographing cyclotrons are maybe slightly misguided. I mean do you know how much iron ore this country exports how is building something huge expected to be beyond my perceivable scope of possibility